# I need to change the html elements of a table with different id using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have two tables with different id, what I would like is table 1 to display food items from db and table 2 to display clothes. However I don't get how to access id and change it using php. I am aware that ajax and jquery would make it simpler but I just want to learn how to do this in the backend.

```
<h3>Lunch/drinks </h3>
<table id= '1' border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Product Name</td>
  <td>Product price</td>
  <td>Product image</td>
</tr>

<h4> Uniforms </h4>
<table id = '2' border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Product Name</td>
  <td>Product price</td>
  <td>Product image</td>
</tr>

<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$sql = "Select PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTPRICE From PRODUCT Where PRODUCTType = 'food'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo
   "<tr>
    <td>{$row['PRODUCTNAME']}</td>
    <td>{$row['PRODUCTPRICE']}</td>
       </tr>\n";
}
$sqlq = "Select PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTPRICE From PRODUCT Where PRODUCTType = 'Uniform'";
$queryq = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlq);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryq)) {
  echo
   "<tr>
    <td>{$row['PRODUCTNAME']}</td>
    <td>{$row['PRODUCTPRICE']}</td>
       </tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>
</table>
```

So what this code does is obviously put all the data in a single table, but I want two different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reorder what you already had. You were almost there:

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
?>
<h3>Lunch/drinks </h3>
<table id= '1' border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Product Name</td>
  <td>Product price</td>
  <td>Product image</td>
</tr>
<?php
$sql = "Select PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTPRICE From PRODUCT Where PRODUCTType = 'food'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo
   "<tr>
    <td>{$row['PRODUCTNAME']}</td>
    <td>{$row['PRODUCTPRICE']}</td>
   </tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>

<h4> Uniforms </h4>
<table id = '2' border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Product Name</td>
  <td>Product price</td>
  <td>Product image</td>
</tr>

<?php
$sqlq = "Select PRODUCTNAME, PRODUCTPRICE From PRODUCT Where PRODUCTType = 'Uniform'";
$queryq = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlq);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryq)) {
  echo
   "<tr>
    <td>{$row['PRODUCTNAME']}</td>
    <td>{$row['PRODUCTPRICE']}</td>
    </tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>
```

> However I don't get how to access id and change it using php

You don't change it in PHP, you make it and that's that. If you want to change it on the fly, after it's been rendered in the browser, that's via jquery. If you made an AJAX call let's say, a PHP script would get called that'd run do a DB query and retrieve the data from the row. That data would then be sent back to the browser and jquery could catch it and change the contents of the table.